# With VBA how do i make the row above the "active row" in a table

Tags: excel, vba

When I insert a row in a table, it inserts a row above the current row, which is fine. But then I need to be able to make that row I just inserted the active row. How would I do that? The structure of my code is:

```
For each row in [Table]
  If [condition] Then
    row.Insert 'this inserts a row above the "current" row
    'here I want to move to the row I just inserted
    ActiveSheet.Cells(row.row, [Table[Col]].Column) = 5 'arbitrary value
  End If
Next row
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that there is no real way to do this... so I used a workaround. I put a `do while` loop around my `for` loop that loops until you get to the last row of the table. Then in the `for` loop I had it exit the loop after every row insert/deletion and added an `elseif` that deals with blank (inserted) rows.

```
Dim ExitLoop As Boolean: ExitLoop = False

Do While ExitLoop = False
    For Each row In [BacklogProjections].Rows
        If (some condition) Then
            row.Delete
            Exit For
        ElseIf (blank row) Then
            'copy appropriate data here
        ElseIf (other condition) Then
            row.Insert
            Exit For
        End If
        'backlogLastRow was initialized somewhere else in my code
        If row.row = backlogLastRow Then ExitLoop = True
    Next row
Loop
```

Answer (score 1):

Try OFFSET (row_no, col_no)

```css
'To go to previous row use this
ActiveCell.Offset(-1, 0).Activate
'To got to next row use this
ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Activate
```

You can try the below code as well :)

```css
Sub test()
a = ActiveCell.Row - 1
Rows(a).Activate
End Sub
```

Incorporated with your code

```css
For Each Row In [Table]
  If [Condition] Then
    Row.Insert 'this inserts a row above the "current" row
    'here I want to move to the row I just inserted
    a = ActiveCell.Row - 1
    Rows(a).Activate
  End If
Next Row
```

Comment: This one offsets the celI I have selected, but it does not work for moving to the previous row in the for loop.

Comment: This doesn't work either. The code you gave correctly changes the highlighted row, but that is something different from what I need. I need the for loop to move `row` to the previous row in the table. I tried `row = row.previous`, but that does not work either.

Comment: The reason why the `rows.activate` method doesn't work is because it deals only with the selected cell. But I need the `row` "object" I declared to be the one changed. Thanks for your efforts, but I have found a workaround for this.

Comment: Glad to know that you got it what you want :) It just sample code how you can select the previous row from the active row/cell..